# Can I get candy faster?

Tags: candy-box

In Candy Box, I've finished a few quests and bought a few swords, but I always seem to get candy at the same rate. Is there any way to get it faster, or am I stuck getting it at this rate forever?

Comment: Depending on how honest you are, you can poke around in the .js console, and turn up the candies-per-second rate without too much trouble. It makes it so you don't need several days to make decent progress.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it looks like the lollipop/second rate maxes out at 100 lollipop/second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you reach the Sorceress' Hut, you can buy candy speed increases for many many lollipops.

You can also get an item that triples your candy acquisition, as well as earning candies from quests.

Comment: Emphasis on MANY

Answer (score 0):

What I do is repeat a quest that gives a lot of candies but at the same time you don't lose too much health so you can quickly do it over and over. I'm stuck on Castle's keep so I get my candies from Underwater Cave.